# SMTP Error 454 4.7.0 during sending email through Gmail API

Tags: smtp, google-oauth, phpmailer, gmail-api, google-workspace

We are facing an error during sending emails from our website through gmail with custom domain.

It was working for years for us, but last week error appeared.

In our logs we're seeing this:

SMTP ERROR 454 4.7.0 Too many login attempts, please try again later.

We're trying to send email with PHPMailer based script. Our sending script uses XOAUTH2 credentials. And everything was fine before we enabled 2 step verification at our account that we use to send emails. And I could tell you more, that everything was ok for almost a week after enabling of 2 step verification, but then error appeared.

We already tried to reissue our refresh token for XOAUTH2. And already tried to disable 2 step verification and then reissue refresh token. And also we tried to send emails with 2 step verification enabled with app password instead of XOAUTH2 token. Nothing helped. And we're still getting the same error. We also tried to wait for 24 hours - it didn't helped too.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code

Comment: Are you sure your not sending to many emails? https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en

Comment: IME, Google replies with this error when authentication fails even once, so it is most likely to be an auth error. It may be rate limiting too though. I suggest contacting Google support to see if there is an issue with your account.